# Ant: ":" and ";" as separator characters are not correctly read in classpath

Tags: java, ant

I have a little problem in specifying my classpath in my new Ant build file:

```
<path id="classpath">
 <fileset dir="${extdirs}">
   <include name="**/*.jar"/>
 </fileset>  
</path>
```

I get this :

```
BUILD FAILED
/home/amira/workspace/srd/clients/ill/impressions/ILLBLI2/build.xml:46: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/amira/workspace/srd/clients/ill/impressions/ILLBLI2/build.xml:12:
/home/amira/workspace/extdirs/common:/home/amira/workspace/extdirs/vaadin:   
/home/amira/workspace/extdirs/remap:/home/amira/workspace/extdirs/axis2:/home/amira/workspace/extdirs/axis1 does not exist.
```

I tried this :

```
 <pathelement path="${extdirs}"/>
```

But the problem persists. and here's the output:

```
BUILD FAILED
 /home/amira/workspace/srd/clients/ill/impressions/ILLBLI2/build.xml:46: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/amira/workspace/srd/clients/ill/impressions/ILLBLI2/build.xml:12: taskdef class net.sf.jasperreports.ant.JRAntCompileTask cannot be found
using the classloader AntClassLoader[/home/amira/workspace/extdirs/common:   
/home/amira/workspace/extdirs/vaadin:/home/amira/workspace/extdirs/remap:     
/home/amira/workspace/extdirs/axis2:/home/amira/workspace/extdirs/axis1]

Total time: 0 seconds
make: *** [compile.stamp] Error 1
```

Here's the content of my EXTDIRS variable:

> echo ${EXTDIRS}
>   /home/amira/workspace/extdirs/common:/home/amira/workspace/extdirs/vaadin:/home/amira/workspace/extdirs/remap:/home/amira/workspace/extdirs/axis2:/home/amira/workspace/extdirs/axis1

Answer (score 3):

As Ravi Thapliyal says, `fileset` only works for a single directory, you want to use `multirootfileset` instead.  Unfortunately this one needs a comma-delimited set of directories so it gets a bit more difficult.

```
<pathconvert property="extdirs-comma-separated"
             dirsep=",">
  <path path="${extdirs}"/>
</pathconvert>
<path id="classpath">
  <multirootfileset basedirs="${extdirs-comma-separated}">
    <include name="**/*.jar"/>
  </multirootfileset>
</path>
```

should work.

Comment: i tried it but i get this: Path doesn't support the nested "multirootfileset" element.

Comment: `multirootfileset` has been added in Ant 1.9.4, are you using an older version?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `<fileset>` expects a ***single*** root directory from which you then include multiple files that match your `<include>` pattern. From your `${extdirs}` value, I suggest the `<property>` declaration to be

```
<property name="extdirs" value="/home/amira/workspace/extdirs" />
```